# Watir returning incorrect child table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir

I have two tables with the same attributes (`random-attribute`) which is the most unique way of identifying them. The only way to differentiate them is by their parent div they belong to (see example below).

```
<div class="header">
    <table random-attribute="left-desc">
    </table>
    <table random-attribute="main-desc">
    </table>
<div>
<div class="body">
    <table random-attribute="left-desc">
    </table>
    <table random-attribute="main-desc">
    </table>
<div>
```

I am trying to get the contents of the table `main-desc` that belongs to     `<div class="body">` but the below code keeps on returning me the table contents of `<div class="header">`

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto(MY_URL_PAGE)
browser.div(class: "body").table(xpath: '//table[@random-attribute="main-desc"]')
```

The weird part is if I run `browser.div(class: "body")` it returns the contents of the correct table but when I chain it as `browser.div(class: "body").table(xpath: '//table[@random-attribute="main-desc"]')` it returns the table from `browser.div(class: "header")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, If you use `//` then it directly searches the relative path in the html, It doesn't search under the `div()`, to make the search under div, you have to use `.` infront of `//` which means you have to use `.//`

So write the following code it would work for you

```
p b.div(class: "body").table(xpath: './/table[@random-attribute="main-desc"]').parent.html
```

Output

```
"<div class=\"body\">\n    <table random-attribute=\"left-desc\">\n    </table>\n    <table random-attribute=\"main-desc\">\n    </table>\n</div>"
```

Or you can directly form the xpath as shown below

```
p b.element(xpath: "//div[@class='body']/table[@random-attribute='main-desc']").parent.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Remembering to include the initial dot of the XPath is one of the reasons Watir tries to avoid XPath. To avoid XPath you can do:

```
browser.div(class: "body").table(random_attribute: "main-desc")
```